# Is there anywhere I can use SymPy online?

Tags: math-software

Are there any websites that allow you to use SymPy in a similar way as Mathematica or MatLab online? I would like to learn and use SymPy for plotting but I own a chromebook and I am limited to only web applications.

Comment: You mean like a [Jupyter notebook](https://try.jupyter.org/)?

Comment: The official SymPy website has a link to a live shell, even!

Comment: @rschwieb I just found cloud.sagemath.com -  is Jupiter an online python environment? It's not loading on my work computer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel - I know! I was just looking for something where I could write and execute a program to solve a problem.

Comment: Sage Math Cloud is really cool, believe me :) It is online service with Ubuntu machines and almost every scientific package that you might need. Needless to say that it has all major scientific libraries for Python, C/C++ and some other languages.

Comment: @user412570 Jupyter is a web-based python interpreter(-ish).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SymPy live](http://live.sympy.org/) website for simple algebra. 
But, I'm not sure how you can plot something.